# Switch statement with string wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, break

I came across this basic question, where switch case is used with string.

Break statement is not used between cases but why it going to all the cases even when it is not matching the case string?

So I'm curious to know 
**why is the output 3 and not 1?**

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
      {
        int wd=0;

        String days[]={"sun","mon","wed","sat"};

        for(String s:days)
        {
          switch (s)
          {
          case "sat":
          case "sun":
            wd-=1;
            break;
          case "mon":
            wd++;
          case "wed":
            wd+=2;
          }
        }
        System.out.println(wd);
      }
```

Comment: But your code contains a break statement.

Comment: you should had use **"debug"** before posting your question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a `break;` at the end of `case "mon"` so value is also incremented by 2

which you didn't expect, flow:

```
0    -1   -1   +1+2  +2 = 3
^     ^    ^   ^     ^
init sat  sun  mon  wed
```

Adding a break as below will result with output 1

```
case "mon":
  wd++;
  break;
```

Comment: This is what I am not able to understand. "mon" is not equal to "wed" so why the value is getting incremented by two?

Comment: @ChandreshMishra switch is finding `mon` and it continue to `wd+=2;` because there's no stopping `break;`, you can test different flows it by removing existing `break;`

Comment: Thanks man. what I was thinking that Break will only stop the unnecessary checking and save the cpu and time. lol.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `break;` at the end of cases for "sat" and "mon". 
This means that when an element matches "sat" and "mon" `case` it will execute the code contained in that case but then fall into the next case.

When the `break` is reached, it breaks out of the switch block. 
This will stop the execution of more code and case testing inside the block.

In this instance. When it tests "sat" and "mon", it does not see a `break` and therefore continues testing.

```
0   -1    0    2    4    3
^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
    sun  mon  mon  wed  sat
```